# How to get MIN(opened_date) and all Open Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

I have some data that looks like this:

| Number | CI | PLUGIN | Opened Date | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | A123 | 1/1/2023 | Closed |
| 2 | XYZ | A123 | 2/1/2023 | Closed |
| 3 | XYZ | A123 | 3/1/2023 | Closed |
| 4 | XYZ | A123 | 4/1/2023 | Open |
| 5 | XYZ | A123 | 5/1/2023 | Open |

I want the result of the query to either give me:

- Only the oldest record (record with minimum opened date), and the two Open records:

| Number | CI | PLUGIN | Opened Date | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | A123 | 1/1/2023 | Closed |
| 4 | XYZ | A123 | 4/1/2023 | Open |
| 5 | XYZ | A123 | 5/1/2023 | Open |

- Or only the two open records and a created a column for the minimum opened date:

| Number | CI | PLUGIN | Opened Date | State | MIN Opened Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | XYZ | A123 | 4/1/2023 | Open | 1/1/2023 |
| 5 | XYZ | A123 | 5/1/2023 | Open | 1/1/2023 |

I tried to filter on State = Open OR min(opened_at) = opened_at but I get the error that aggregate can't be used in the where clause.

I tried using MAX(number) in the query with MIN(opened_at), but then I only get the record for Number = 5. I also need to have record Number = 4.

I also tried creating two queries, one with only open records and one with MIN(Opened Date) and unioning them, but that just gave me all the records.

Using SSMS 19.
SQL Server (Windows SQL Server)
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You wrote: _I tried_ [Edit] your question and post the SQL that you tried. It may also help if you post the structure(s) of the [database] table(s), i.e. the column names and their data types.

Comment: In case you want to use aggregates, you will also need to specify a `GROUP BY` clause. You can apply filtering on aggregated results using a `HAVING` clause. 

I.e. `SELECT CI, Plugin, MIN(Opened_Date) FROM Table GROUP BY CI, Plugin, HAVING Opened_Date >= '2023-04-01'` would give you a list of all combinations of CI, Plugin that were first opened after April 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just didn't wrap it in a sub query so the windowed function is available to the where clause:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Number INT, CI NVARCHAR(3), PLUGIN NVARCHAR(4), OpenedDate DATE, State NVARCHAR(6));

INSERT INTO @Table (Number, CI, PLUGIN, OpenedDate, State) VALUES
(1, 'XYZ', 'A123', '1/1/2023', 'Closed'),
(2, 'XYZ', 'A123', '2/1/2023', 'Closed'),
(3, 'XYZ', 'A123', '3/1/2023', 'Closed'),
(4, 'XYZ', 'A123', '4/1/2023', 'Open'),
(5, 'XYZ', 'A123', '5/1/2023', 'Open');

SELECT a.Number, a.CI, a.PLUGIN, a.OpenedDate, a.State, a.MinOpenDate
  FROM (
        SELECT a.Number, a.CI, a.PLUGIN, a.OpenedDate, a.State, MIN(a.OpenedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY a.CI, a.Plugin ORDER BY a.OpenedDate) AS MinOpenDate
          FROM @Table a
       ) a
 WHERE a.OpenedDate = a.MinOpenDate
    OR a.State = 'Open'
```

We're doing exactly what you described, but we can now referenced the windowed aggregate column in the where clause.

Just as a side note, providing easily reproduceable DDL/DML make it much easier for folks to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, @Patrick. This did the trick. I'm going to go look up PARTITION BY and read up on that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can think of `PARTITION BY` a bit like `GROUP BY` but just for the window you're describing. In this example we have asked for the minimum `OpenedDate` for each group distinct pair of `CI` and `Plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

We use window functino `min()over()` to find the first date and then `where` to only display `state = 'open'`. Notice it has to be nested or it will filter out the the `min(Opened_Date)`.

```
select *
from
(
select *
      ,first_value(Opened_Date) over(order by Opened_Date) as MIN_Opened_Date
from   t
) t
where State = 'Open'
```

| Number | CI | PLUGIN | Opened_Date | State | MIN_Opened_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | XYZ | A123 | 2023-04-01 | Open | 2023-01-01 |
| 5 | XYZ | A123 | 2023-05-01 | Open | 2023-01-01 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2ezCSpDp)

Comment: Thank you @DannySlor, this helped get me on the started down the subquery route. I appreciate your help.